# Is there a way for a web-application to determine if the browser is running on a personal computer?

Tags: browser, environment

I've got a web-application that a user logs into after creating their account.  As part of the account creation process the user can indicate that the computer/device being used is their own device, in which case the IP-Address of that device is remembered along with the other user's information, additionally the browser will ask if it should save the user's username and password to the browser's built-in username/password management 'system'.  If the user chooses to save their account credentials to the browser, then the user will be able to select their username and password from the browser's pop-up list of credentials the next time that they log into my web-application's login screen and bypass the need to type that information in.

This is all fine for personal computers and devices, but on library, schools, and other public computers, I don't want users to save their credentials on these computers.

Is there some way to infer that the computer that the user is running browser on is a public or private computer?  Possibly using a look-up service on the IP-Address or the computer environment information that the browser shares with the server running my web-application?

Comment: Ask the user whether or not to store personal information on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You're really asking two different questions:

Q1: How can I tell what kind of device the client is running my web app on?

A1: There are several choices:

- Server-side: you can use your favorite HTTP library to query the client's [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)\
- Client-side: you can use Javascript for [user agent sniffing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent)

Q2: How do I discourage/prevent a user from saving confidential information in an insecure environment?

A2: Again, the are different alternatives.  You should consider *all* of them:

- Your site should *definitely* be using HTTPS (if it isn't already)
- The easiest approach is to present a dialog and *ask* if their connection is "safe"
- You might also read the [OWASP Top Ten Security Risks](https://blog.sucuri.net/2019/01/owasp-top-10-security-risks-part-iv.html)

Comment: To both responses, Thanks.  Yes, I am already asking if the device is owned by the user, and if they say yes, then I let the browser prompt them to save their username and password.  I was just wondering if there was more information that I might be able to get from the browser or a look-up service that could improve detecting libraries, schools, etc.

Comment: No, it doesn't sound like you've left any of the bases uncovered ;)  And as long as you're already putting up an alert, I would definitely make sure the alert explains that the reason you're asking is to ensure the user's "security" - they shouldn't be adding any passwords to a device they don't "own".  That you're not just asking "to be nosy" ;)  And please *DO* read through the OWASP materials, if you're not already familiar with them.  Q: Does that help?  Or TL;DR?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.